# Remove query strings from 301 redirect

Tags: apache, redirect, query-string, http-status-code-301

I am struggling to create appropriate 301 redirects for a site that was originally built using query strings. The old URL structure looks like this:

```
http://www.oldsite.com/about/index.cfm?fuseaction=cor_av&artID=5049
```

I want to redirect the entire subfolder (named 'about') to a new page on the new domain. The new domain's URL looks like this:

```
http://www.newsite.com/info
```

So, I set up a redirect that looks like this:

```
redirectMatch 301 ^/about/ http://www.newsite.com/info
```

It is redirecting just fine, but it's keeping the original URL string attached, so the new URL ends up looking like this in a browser:

```
http://www.newsite.com/info/?fuseaction=cor_av&artID=5049
```

I'm definitely not enough of an Apache/301 expert ot know how to fix this. I just want to strip off everything from the ? on.

Really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

two options:

```
redirectMatch 301 ^/about/ http://www.newsite.com/info?
```

or:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^about/(.*) http://www.newsite.com/info? [L,R=301]
```

question mark at the end seems to be the critical bit. Second one looks a little cleaner (first leaves a question mark at the end of your URL)

Comment: Note that on Apache >= 2.4, you can use the QSD flag rather than adding an ending question mark :
`RewriteRule ^about/(.*) http://www.newsite.com/info [`QSD`,L,R=301]`

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this code into the `.htaccess` that specified for `oldsite.com`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/about/index.cfm$
RewriteRule ^(.+) http://www.newsite.com/info/ [R=301,QSA]
```

Follow up?

Comment: Nope, the `QSA` **a**ppends the old query string to the new url.  To **d**iscard it, use the flag is `QSD` (apache >=2.4) or just add an `?` as in the accepted answer. See [Apache RewriteRule Flags](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa)

Comment: Yes, QSA should be replaced with QSD. This options is available since *apache 2.4* .