# Htaccess 301 redirect is adding ?folder= to URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm attempting to perform a simple 301 redirect via htaccess, the redirect works but adds "?folder=X" to the URL.

For instance:

```
Redirect 301 /pets http://www.mydomain.com/discount-pet-products
```

Returns:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/discount-pet-products?folder=pets
```

How do I remove this?

Here is my htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
Redirect 301 /pets http://www.mydomain.com/discount-pet-products
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)$ load.php?folder=$1 [L]
```

Comment: let you want X url to Y. then what is x & y?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand this question?

Comment: Maybe you have a query string that contain `folder=X`? Is so, this would help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10708301/remove-query-strings-from-301-redirect

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^/pets$ http://www.mydomain.com/discount-pet-products? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)$ load.php?folder=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks but no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 

RewriteRule ^pets/$ /discount-pet-products? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/?$ load.php?folder=$1 [L,QSA]
```

**Make sure to test this in a new browser to avoid browser caching issues.**

Answer (score 0):

The answer was placing redirect at top of .htaccess file, before anything

```
RewriteRule ^pets$ http://www.mydomain.co.uk/discount-pet-products [R=301,L]
```