# Remove var from links using htaccess redirect

Tags: .htaccess

I have read a lot of answers about this but could not find the solution.

At this moment I made a redirect in htaccess:

```
Redirect 301 /best-verkocht?p=1 https://website.nl
Redirect 301 /best-verkocht?p=2 https://website.nl
Redirect 301 /best-verkocht?p=3 https://website.nl
```

The result is that the following link is made: https://website.nl/?p=1

What is the best and most easy way get rid of this var?

Comment: Dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10708301/remove-query-strings-from-301-redirect

Comment: Tried that but did not work as the link is just a bit different. I dont have a / in the end...

Answer (score 0):

```
Redirect 301 /best-verkocht https://website.nl?
```

If you need to limit your matches to the `p` values 1, 2, and 3, then you'll need to use mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=(1|2|3)$
RewriteRule ^best-verkocht$ https://website.nl [L,R=301]
```